# Integrate card.io With Web Based App

Tags: card.io

We prefer to use web based apps with jquery.mobile as they can get upgraded on demand and just less hassle.  Is there an api that can be called by ajax from our web based app to use the card.io service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid not. To make for a responsive, reliable user experience, card.io actually examines many video frames to select good quality ones for processing. We also process them client-side, because with large images the latency from the network round trip can be significant.

This all requires non-trivial client-side work. There are two immediate problems to porting to html: (1) performance and (2) camera APIs.

### Performance

Javascript interpreters are fast, but when doing image processing, native code is a huge help. (card.io uses the GPU, the ARM vector co-processor, and drops down to assembly in a few places.) Access to the GPU via Canvas will help, but not all algorithms are amenable to GPU treatment. Performance will continue to become less critical over time, but it's a major challenge right now.

### Camera APIs

Camera API support is very uneven across mobile browsers, and (to my knowledge, at time of writing), none of the major mobile browsers (Mobile Safari, Chrome, Firefox) provide full realtime video access with enough control over resolution to make processing the stream feasible. Again, hopefully this will change.

I hold out hope that there will someday be a mobile web version of card.io, but it's definitely not available now (although we do have a Phone Gap plugin.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, we will still be able to use the service we will just have to hook in an app.  Thanks

Comment: @josh-bleecher-snyder this answer was from 5 years ago. Any developments now? Seems like a javascript port of card.io would be possible with today's javascript environment.